# Regex is always greedy, even when I give it non-capturing parentheses?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have strings like this:

```
strings = [
'title : Booking things author J smith',
'title : Unbe God author:  K. sweet'
]
```

the strings may or may not have colons between "title" and the title, and between "author" and the author.  but they will always have the words "title" and "author".

and I want to capture the title like this:  `Booking things`, and `Unbe God`.

I have two regexes:

```
regex1 = '(?:title\s*:?\s*)[\w\s]+(?=author)'
regex2 = '(?<=title)(?:\s*:?\s*)[\w\s]+(?=author)' # bad because regex is greedy?
```

The result is:
regex1:

```
import re
re.findall(regex1, string, flags=re.I)
['title : Booking things ']
```

regex2:

```
import re
re.findall(regex2, string, flags=re.I)
[' : Booking things ']
```

For the first, `regex1`, I thought that the non-capturing `(?:)` would tell it not to capture the word `title`.  How do I tell it to not capture the word `title` without using a lookbehind?

IN the second one, `regex2`, I do use a look-behind, but then I face a similar problem.  How do I tell it to not capture the `:`, but still look behind for the word `title`?  I'm also avoiding the fact that look-behind must be fixed-width.

Comment: Use `(?:title\s*:?\s*)([\w\s]+)(?=author)` with `re.findall`. The captured text will be in Group 1.

Comment: Use `'(?::\s+)(.*)(?=\s+author)'`

Comment: Non-capturing groups have nothing to do with greediness.

Comment: Surely not. Greediness only pertains to quantifiers. `.*m` is a greedy subpattern as `.` will be matched 0 or more times but as many times as possible, up to the last `m`. `.*?m` will match zero or more characters as few times as possible, up to the first `m`.

Comment: Here's an edge case for your regex testing: the author's name is "I am an author"

Comment: @glennjackman: in this case, you need to catch the last "author" occurence. (except is the author call himself "author")

Comment: my main point was that this is a poor data structure.

Comment: @glennjackman: Yeah, that would make regex look nasty: [`(?:title\s*:?\s*)([\w\s]+?)\s+(?=\bauthor\b(?:(?!\bauthor\b).)*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/pA2hH2/3)

Comment: @stribizhev: you can write it like this: https://regex101.com/r/nQ0eE8/1

Comment: @stribizhev: or like this: https://regex101.com/r/nQ0eE8/2

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Both take more steps to complete than mine.

Comment: @stribizhev: are you sure? Look more carefully at the test string.

Comment: Ok, you used a different one. Emulating atomic groups is something I am unable to do at  night. I am watching a sci fi film - please let me watch and I will answer any critique tomorrow.

Comment: @stribizhev: ahah! I am the devil!

Comment: Right, so, as @stribizhev said, "non-capturing groups still consume text".  What is the difference between "consuming text" and capturing?  Because, even in my `regex1`, when I ask `title` to not be captured by including it in the `(?:)`, it still is returned by the regex?

Comment: Capturing is a part of matching. Consuming means the characters matched by regex are added to the match value that will be returned as output of the match operation. When you ask not to be captured that only means *do not save that part of the match value in a specific numbered or named buffer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought that the non-capturing `(?:)` would tell it not to capture the word title

*Non-capturing groups* **still consume text**. They just *match* (text is grabbed and added to the matching result), do not *capture* (=store a part of the matched value in a specific numbered or named buffer). To check for presence/absence, there are lookarounds only (or anchors).

It is clear you want to discard the prefix `title :` from the matches. You cannot use a lookbehind since in Python `re` module a *variable-width* lookbehind (the one with quantifiers inside) isn't allowed. A usual workaround is to use *capturing groups* around the patterns you need to get.

You can set a capturing group around the `[\w\s]+` subpattern to capture that value into Group 1:

```
import re
strings = [
'title : Booking things author J smith',
'title : Unbe God author:  K. sweet'
]
for x in strings:
    m = re.search(r"(?:title\s*:?\s*)([\w\s]+)(?=author)", x)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output of the [sample demo](http://ideone.com/BTPsf3):

```
Booking things 
Unbe God
```

Note that if you want to get rid of the trailing whitespace in the captured texts, use a bit adjusted regex:

```
(?:title\s*:?\s*)([\w\s]+?)\s+(?=author)
                         ^
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pA2hH2/2). The `?` makes the `[\w\s]+` subpattern *lazy* and will match as few characters as possible before 1 or more whitespaces (`\s+`) that are right before a sequence of literal characters `author`.

Comment: So, if `(?: )` is a non-capturing group, and `()` is a capturing group, what is the default?

Comment: @Sother: I do not understand what you mean by default. If you need to capture and then use the captured text in your code, use a capturing group. If you just need a grouping construct, say, for alternative definition, you can use a non-capturing one.

Comment: Check my question, in `regex1`.  Is the `[\w\s]+` captured?  or not captured?  It has no `()` and no `(?:)` around it.  That's what I mean when I ask what the default is.

Comment: See what [*matching*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) is:  *A "match" is the piece of text, or sequence of bytes or characters that pattern was found to correspond to by the regex processing software.* When we speak about *capturing*, we only mean [*storing the part of the string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the parentheses*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). When `[\w\s]+` is not encloses with round brackets, the matched value is not stored in a specific buffer (=not captured). These are basics of regexp.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your persistence, I can feel myself getting closer.  So, everything that is `captured` is also `match`ed, got it.  And, `findall` returns what is *matched* rather than what is *captured*. But, by that logic, changing what is captured should not change what is matched.  So I'm still trying to figure out why adding `()` changes the fact that "`title`" is matched, when I didn't change whether `title` was matched or not.

Comment: `re.findall` returns captured texts, not the whole matched text. Adding `()` or `(?:)` does not prevent from something being matched. But when we tell to capture something, we can later use it separately from the match.

Comment: I just read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) and it says that `findall` returns matches?   I think

Comment: I think you misunderstand my beef with `title`:  The original regex1 was : `(?:title\s*:?\s*)[\w\s]+(?=author)`, and then  I add `()` around `[\w\s]+` (NOT around anything to do with `title`) to get: `(?:title\s*:?\s*)([\w\s]+)(?=author)`....which changes what is returned by `findall`.  How does changing the capturing of `[\w\s]+` affect the *matching* of `title`?

Comment: Read [`re.findall` reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall): *If one or more [capturing] groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.* When you add a capturing group, `re.findall` won't return you the whole match, only the captured substrings (submatches). Use `re.finditer` that will return match objects where you will be able to reference the whole match by Group 0.

Comment: I see, so the word `group` is always associated with `capturing groups`.  So, if there are no `()` present, then it returns the matches, but if there are `()`s present, then it returns only the capturing groups.

Comment: Right. Just FYI: unescaped parentheses may define an inline modifier. `(?i)` means in Python that the whole pattern is case insensitive and in C# it means that the rest of the pattern to the right is case insensitive. In C#, you can even define case insensitive blocks using `(?i:pattern)` notation. These are not *groups*.